# Logging JBoss request/response ONLY using log4j

Tags: jboss, log4j, jboss7.x

How can *JBoss* **requests/responses** ONLY be logged using *log4j*?

For my 3-tiered application (client, web-service and database), I'm trying to gather request/response times.

For instance, **timestamps** before/after:

1. Client sends request
2. WS receives request
3. WS sends query to database

Currently, my log displays several **thousand lines** of text (`DEBUG` mode). But, I'm looking only for request/response information.

I suppose I could choose a different **log** [**level**](http://docs.jboss.org/process-guide/en/html/logging.html), but I'm not able to find my `log4j.xml` that most [solutions](http://java.dzone.com/articles/configuring-logging-jboss) are referring to (`server/xxx/conf/jboss-log4j.xml`). The `log4j.properties` file in my *Eclipse* for some reason is not allowing edits.

I'm new to *JBoss*; in fact inherited the current setup from somebody else, so I'm a little clueless about the entire `JBoss` thing.

### Edit 1

Examples of `log4j.properties` can be found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/).

### Edit 2

My `log4j.properties`:

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C\:log4j.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.category.org.springframework.beans.factory=DEBUG
```

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins JBoss-AS-7.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably best to configure logging through the [logging subsystem](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+To). If you're looking to use your a log4j configuration file, see the instructions [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+To#HowTo-HowdoIuselog4j.propertiesorlog4j.xmlinsteadofusingtheloggingsubsystemconfiguration%3F).

Comment: The *log4j* option worked; `log4j.properties` file is now editable. Though, it's not displaying all the **request/response** timestamps that I'm looking for (even in the `TRACE` level). I guess I should check if the **category priority threshold** is enabled.

Comment: Could you add your log4j configuration?

Comment: I added my `log4j.properties` under **Edit 2**.

Comment: Try adding
`log4j.appender.file.threshold=TRACE`

Comment: That doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: You're not by chance using slf4j too are you? If so, add that to the exclusion list in your `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`.

Comment: Just looked at the *lib* directory; that's not being used. I tried using the *Logging Subsystem*. It appears to be doing a more fine-grained logging. However, it might take me a very long time to figure out how I can get only the **HTTP request/response** logs and also the **SQL session** logs. There's a lot about the code that I don't understand.

Comment: You can always visit the JBoss Community forums too https://community.jboss.org/en/jbossas7. There is a lot of useful information specific to JBoss AS 7 there as well as other things JBoss.